# find duplicate data between files in unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have 2 files with contents:-

file1:

```
918802944821    919968005200    kushinagar
919711354546    919211999924    delhi
915555555555    916666666666    kanpur
919711354546    915686524578    hehe
918802944821    4752168549  hfhkjh
```

file2:-

```
919211999924    919711354546    ghaziabad
919999999999    918888888888    lucknow
912222222222    911111111111    chandauli
918802944821    916325478965    hfhjdhjd
```

Now notice that number1 and number2 are interchanged in file1 and file2. I want to print only this duplicate line on the screen. to be more specific i want only the numbers or line to be printed on the screen which are duplicate like 8888888888 and 7777777777 are duplicate in the two files. I want only these two numbers on the screen or the whole line on the screen..

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]++;next} a[$2,$1]' f1 f2
7777777777    8888888888    pqr
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;b[$2]++;next} a[$1] || b[$1] {print $1} a[$2] || b[$2]{print $2}' f1 f2
919211999924
919711354546
918802944821
```

Comment: this is not correct, didn't test if `f1.$2 == f2.$1`

Comment: I am little unclear what the exact requirement is but output is from above command only.

Comment: requirement is i want to print all the similar numbers or the complete row which are duplicate in two or more files (more files means suppose there are 100 files in a directory). I NEED TO PRINT ONLY THOSE NUMBERS OR COMPLETE ROW WHICH ARE DUPLICATE

Comment: Ok can you provide more sample data in your question with your expected output.

Comment: I suggested sample data in question, not in comments since it is impossible to understand from comments. Also provide your expected output.

Comment: expected answer is: 919211999924 919711354546 918802944821

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2 FS $1]=1;next}a[$1 FS $2]{print $1,$2}' f1 f2   
7777777777 8888888888
```

Comment: thank you so much.

What if i have thousand numbers in number1 column and another thousand numbers in number2 column. Note: thousands means i dont know the exact limit.

please help

Comment: @user2617138 "thousand" means nothing for the line in my answer, give it a try.

Comment: i have modified the question please look